# Error passing information from javascript to query database with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get the user's location with the HTML5 Geolocation. With the latitude and longitude that I get I want to query a database using php to get the closest locations within 25 miles.  The javascript I have works to get the user location as well as printing out the latitude and longitude but when I call my php file to get the close locations it doesn't seem to be working.

**EDIT 2:** **It seems like `getClosest()` isn't being called because the sample printout doesn't even print into my `<p id="r">`**

**EDIT:** I edited my php code so it works now when I go straight to the php link but it doesn't seem to be getting the information from the javascript because it's not being printed onto the first page.

Thanks in advance. Here is my html/javascript:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
<p id="r">...</p>

  <script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var txt = document.getElementById("txtHint");
  var r = document.getElementById("r");

  function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

  getClosest(lat,lon);

  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lat + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + lon;  


  }

 function getClosest(lat,lon) {
  r.innerHTML = "DSHFAOSIGIUSDOFDSJF";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    txt.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  }
  </script>
```

And here is my php:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "hello";


        echo "aghasldfha";
    $q = $_GET['lon'];
    $p = $_GET['lat'];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        mysqli_select_db($con,"db");
        $sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$p."') ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians('".$q."') ) + sin( radians('".$p."') ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Events HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        echo "<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Longitude</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Latitude'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Longitude'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top in php file  to see if your are getting any error in php.

Comment: There is still nothing showing up at all

Comment: I checked `xmlhttp.responseText` and I get nothing from it. I may not be using that right either, but I figure the problem is with the php since the page won't even echo something simple at the top of the php script.  I did change `xmlhttp.open` from true to false on the third param and there's still nothing.

Comment: just put `echo "hello";` in a new PHP file and see if that works on your server ...

Comment: `Echo "hello";` works in a new PHP file on my server

Comment: correct your `else if` to `elseif`

Comment: are you getting latitude and longitude values in your PHP file ?

Comment: also you should be doing `echo` only once in your PHP code. Put other html in to variables, append dynamic variables and then echo once everything is done.

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude values in the PHP file if I put them in the url as `$_GET` values.  It prints out correctly when I manually enter the url in my browser but when I click the button on my first page which calls the php script it doesn't do anything

Comment: try below answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Updated from Comment-

Just a refactoring to make your code more readable and track all the things you are sending from PHP,  you can club all the `echo` statements into one and call it at the end when all your operations are done.

Try this one -

```
$q = $_GET['lon'];
$p = $_GET['lat'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"db");
    $sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$p."') ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians('".$q."') ) + sin( radians('".$p."') ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Events HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $table =  "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    </tr>";

    $rows = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows .= "<tr>"."<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"."<td>" . $row['Latitude'] . "</td>"."<td>" . $row['Longitude'] . "</td>"."</tr>";
    }
    $htmlResult = $table.$rows."</table>";
    echo $htmlResult;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same as before, it works alone but not when it's called by javascript.

Comment: can you use jquery AJAX ...?

Comment: It just seems like `getClosest()` isn't being called

Comment: @Chandan: can you explain what you changed and how it fixes the issue? What was the issue anyway?

Comment: @user3272438: if the function is not called then there may be a client side error. Check the console for errors. Did you allow your side to access your location?

Comment: @user3272438 seems you are not getting the success callback from the geoLocation... please check that

Comment: It turns out that I was editing the wrong file in a different folder location.  I got it to work by copying and pasting what I had to the right file. Thanks for all of the help, I apologize for taking the time away from your evenings.

Comment: did the above answer helped you ??

Comment: *"Your are doing echo multiple times in your PHP code, which is not going to work if its an AJAX call"* Why shouldn't this work? I highly doubt it. @user3272438: Don't accept an answer if it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: @FelixKling the AJAX call will terminate with first echo statement. Unfortunately we still don't have the live update using ajax and multiple echo from PHP. :P  Also, once an header has been sent, you can not modify the headers. So, in some cases this might even cause Error. This is the reason why it wont work.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess this answer did help him ... ;)

Comment: Don't know where you got your information from, but I just verified that when I have two `echo` statements, the output of both is in the response.

Comment: my bad... sorry.. did'nt notice the exit() statement after every echo in my demo code... :(